# Firestore and Paging Library 3.0

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

How do I use Firestore and the new paging library alpha-03 3.0 from the android team.

Google should really review the integration of Firebase apis and android. It is becoming more difficult to use them with the android architectural components

Comment: What code have you tried so far and what problems have you encountered in integrating Firebase?

Comment: Am using MVVM and clean architecture to make android application. I decided to use firebase cloud firestore as a hub for my data. but am having trouble with adding firestore to the new paging library 3.0.0 from the android team. My result data just duplicates itself

Comment: [This post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-pagination-in-android-using-firebaseui-library-1d7fe1a75704) explains how to integrate pagination in Firebase Firestore. If you want us to help you further we will need some code showing what you have tried and what problems you have encountered.

Comment: I think you might be interested in this article, [How to paginate Firestore using Paging 3 on Android?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df).